# How do I call a Module to execute a script from a Sub_Click?

Tags: vba, excel, call

I have 10 macro buttons in my sheet.
I have a Module with a script for a Customer Report.

When button 1 is clicked from the sheet I have created a new macro called Button1_Click(). Inside this script I only would like to set one variable, Row1:

```
Button1_Click()
Dim Row1 As Integer
Row1 = 1
```

From here I want to call the module CustomerReport that contain the full reporting script, and I want to re-use the Row1 value inside CustomerReport script as it identifies Customer 1.

I have tried `Call CustomerReport` but nothing happens. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in Module1 `Public Row1 as Integer`...

In your Sub just `Row1 = 1`

Row1 will be 1 as Long as you dont change it, reload the workbook or reset  your macros... this way you can set it to any value without calling another macro... but you can still use the value later :)

**Edit:**
just for your comment

when crating macros you best work with the standart set pattern:
first set special behaviors like

```
Option Explicit
...
```

as you need it

then declare all global variables and types as you need them
(start with types to declare global variables based on them)

```
Type MyType
  FirstChild As Long
  SecondChild(0 To 20) As Byte
  ThirdChild As String
  ...
End Type

Public dRunner() As Variant
Public MySuperVariable As MyType
...
```

in the third part put all direct functions you need (api)

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
...
```

then all self-created functions

```
Public Function MyModulo(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
  Do Until a < b
    a = a - b
  Loop
  MyModulo = a
End Function
...
```

and then start with your subs... except for `Option Explicit` you wont use most of them... however, just keeping the order saves a lot of trouble :)

Comment: This was the answer most clear, I also figured out I had to set the Public variable BEFORE the Sub_Click. Now it works perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass things around like this:

```
Sub CallingSub()
    Dim Row1 as Long
    Row1 = 1
    Call CalledSub(Row1)
End Sub

Sub CalledSub(Row1 as Long)
    msgbox "Row1 = " & Row1
End Sub
```

You can also shorten this like so:

```
Sub CallingSub()
    Call CalledSub(1) '<-- Putting the 1 in here is fine and the type is not passed anyway, notice in CalledSub we define it as a long within the brackets
End Sub

Sub CalledSub(Row1 as Long)
    msgbox "Row1 = " & Row1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Dan's got the answer right there. In addition to that, you can call methods and functions across modules as well like this:

Module1:

```
Sub Test1()
    MsgBox "Module1 test1"
End Sub

Function GetNewPay(Pay As Integer, RaisePercent As Double) As Double
    GetNewPay = Pay * (1 + (RaisePercent / 100))
End Function
```

Module2:

```
Sub Test1()
    MsgBox "Module2 test1"
    Call Module1.Test1
    Call Test2("Just testing")

    Dim NewPay As Double, OldPay As Integer, RaisePercent As Double
    OldPay = 20000
    RaisePercent = 15
    NewPay = Module1.GetNewPay(OldPay, RaisePercent)

    MsgBox "Old Pay is " & OldPay & ". New pay is " & NewPay & " with " & RaisePercent & "% raise"

End Sub

Sub Test2(Message As String)
    MsgBox "Message is " & Message & " from module2 test1"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (I'm still very newbie) with:
Module1 named Buttons:
`Sub Button1_Click()
 Dim Row1 As Integer
 Row1 = 1
 Call Module.CustomerReport` where Module2 is named CustomerReport.

I just get Run-time error '424 Object required.

Comment: What is the name of the module? Is it CustomerReport? If it is, you will have to type CustomerReport.NameOfYourSubInCustomerReport. If your module is called Module2 and it contains `Sub CustomerReport()`, you will have to call it with `Call Module2.CustomerReport()`

Comment: OP Do you mean you renamed the actual module to CustomerReport? If so then it would be `Call CustomerReport.CustomerReport` (Module name followed by a full stop followed by sub routine name)